# Restrict and change select lists values used along jQuery UI's datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using jQuery UI's datepicker to display a calendar with select lists. Input field and select list are synchronized, so when you change value of either the datepicker or select list, the value of the other fields will change accordingly.

The datepicker is used with the Restrict date range functionality (http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#min-max). That does its job perfectly - the END date can't be before the START date and you are unable to choose previous days accordingly. Of course, you can't choose that the START date is after the END date either.

The problem is with the select list. Even if "restrict date range" does its job, you still can select any date with the select lists. Therefore, I'm looking for this solution when you use the select lists (it shouldn't affect anything if you only use the calendar icon):

1. If you first select the START date, the END date should automatically change to one day after the selected date.
2. If you have both dates selected and decide to change the START date to the date that is after the END date, the END date should again change to one day later.
3. If you have both dates selected and decide to change the END date to the date that is before the START date, the START date should change to one day before the END date.

I have tried with using this piece of code to affect #1 and #2:

```
$('#start').change(function() {
  var date2 = $('#start').datepicker('getDate', '+1d');
  date2.setDate(date2.getDate()+1);
  $('#end').datepicker('setDate', date2);
});
```

However, it doesn't seem to affect anything. Here is the whole example on jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/JW4jg/

Comment: dumb question...why have both systems? Users are all familiar with datepickers. Path you might take to keep both is to store current values of selects and within chnage handler if out of range reset to stored values and notify user. If Not out of range update stored values

Comment: My first idea was also to have only the datepicker, but it might be problematic for mobile users, select lists are much easier for them. Otherwise it would be definitely better for me only to keep the datepicker.